# Suppose B = $B_1 \cup B_2. $ Show that $A \times B = (A \times B_1) \cup (A \times B_2)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it always true that

1. $(A_1 \cap A_2) \times (B_1 \cap B_2) = (A_1\times B_1) \cap (A_2 \times B_2)$ and
2. $(A_1 \cup A_2) \times (B_1 \cup B_2) = (A_1 \times B_1) \cup (A_2 \times B_2)$?

**I've already showed the first part, just trying to prove true/false for parts a and b, thanks!

Comment: The title doesn't match the question, by the way. Not by a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Take $A_2=B_1=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

We can show part 1) is true, but part 2) is false.

For part 2) take $A_1 = \{1\}, A_2 = \{2\}, B_1 = \{3\}, B_2 =\{4\}$. Then in part 2) we have the LHS is $\{1,2\} \times \{3,4\} = \{(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)\}$, while the RHS is $\{(1,3)\}\cup\{(2,4)\} = \{(1,3), (2,4)\}$, and they are not equal as sets.

As for part 1) we show LHS is a subset of RHS and vice versa. So it is true.