# Cartesian product help

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1 = B_1 = [0,1], A_2 = B_2 = [1,2]$

How do I get the result for $(A_1 \cup A_2) \times (B_1 \cup B_2)$

It's been like 3 years since i've had to do this.

Comment: What do you mean, "Get the result for?"

Comment: [If you had in mind particular sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645597/suppose-b-b-1-cup-b-2-show-that-a-times-b-a-times-b-1-cup-a-tim), then you should have said so.

Answer (score 1):

$A_1 \cup A_2=[0,2]= B_1\cup B_2$, so

$$(A_1 \cup A_2) \times (B_1 \cup B_2) = [0,2]^2$$

Answer (score 0):

The cartesian product is creating a tuple by taking an element from the first set and an element from the second set in every combination.  E.g., $\{a,b\}\times\{c,d\}=\{(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d)\}.$

The union is combining the elements of the sets. E.g., $\{a,b\}\cup\{c,d\}=\{a,b,c,d\}.$

This should be enough for you to finish the problem.